# Get selected element in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview, qt5.5

I have a QTreeView which e.g. shows following structure (all in same column):

```
parent 1
 - child 1
 - child 2
 - child 3
parent 2
parent 3
```

Now I make use of a signal currentChanged() to find out which of the elements is selected. But there I get back the same index value 1 for "parent 1" and "child 1" or 2 for "child 2" and "parent 2" - it seems the index always uses the relative row count. So how can I find out which element is selected?

Thanks!

Comment: How will you use the information on selected item? Do you need to know its name or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model index row and column number are relative to the parent model index. Use the `QModelIndex::parent()` method to get the parent index.